# java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size - After Windows OS security patch

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I am attempting to encrypt a string using below method. this method worked successfully before. After Windows OS security patch now i am getting "java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size"

Also i have added local_policy & US_export_policy jar files under C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\jre\lib\security. My OS is Windows7 64 bit.

Its working when i run through Java main method, but when i run through tomcat application i get below exception.

```
public static String encryptData() throws Exception{
        byte[] saltBytes = "myegaes256encryption".getBytes("UTF-8");
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec("myeg@1234".toCharArray(), saltBytes, 65536, 256);
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec("myegaes256ivspec".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

        //Encryption starts here
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal("DD3E5B7BB7D3036FE7CB557B4FEEB05F".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return new Base64().encodeAsString(encryptedBytes);
    }
```

**Exception:**

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size   at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.a(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.a(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.a(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your policy files to `jre/lib/security/`, not `jdk/lib/`

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\jre\lib\security\. I have tried but now working.

Comment: Is it **now** working or is it **not** working? "But" is used to report on a negative, e.g. "I like carrot cake **but** I like pecan cake better". Hmm, getting some carrot cake, bye :)

Comment: @DEADEND If it's not working, do what I mentioned - place your policy files under `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\security` (of course you will have different Java version)